Node and NPM `Command not found`
As screenshot below we can see, on Debian WSL window terminal, node: command not found and the same thing for npm.
But in VScode WSL window terminal that is never happens. Node and NPM package always detected.

But I don't wan't to use VScode terminal while in development, since VScode terminal is really taking high usage and can crash due to over cosumption usage.
QUESTION: Why Node and NPM packages not detected in my native WSL2 Debian terminal? How to fix it?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

If this question is reopened, I can post an official answer. The process for installing node/nvm on WSL is the same as doing it on a mac without homebrew. Make sure curl is installed, run curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/master/install.sh | bash, then nvm install --lts. You may need to restart WSL2, but now node --version and npm --version should work. It's working in VSCode because it was installed through VSCode or with an .exe.

To find out what you are calling, use command -v node. Also check what’s in $PATH. // The Node version you are able to call is entirely outdated and should be updated.

@DrZoo Question reopened.

@OP, Did the steps provided help you resolve your issue?

@DrZoo , yes. Youre right. It's resolve the issue

The process for installing node/nvm on WSL is the same as doing it on a Mac without homebrew.
Make sure cURL is installed with curl -V.
It should be installed, because WSL is a full Linux environment in Windows, and cURL is a native Linux tool. Run curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/master/install.sh | bash, then nvm install --lts.
You may need to restart WSL2, but now node --version and npm --version should work. It's working in VSCode because it was installed through VSCode or with an .exe.
